# Why is my else if function not working properly when I have checked to make sure the values make it true?

Tags: c, backend, cs50

`

```
long get_number(void);
int get_digits(long creditnumber);
int calcfirst(long creditnumber);
bool checksum(long creditnumber, int digits);

int main(void)
{
    long creditnumber = get_number();
    int digits = get_digits(creditnumber);
    int firstdigit = calcfirst(creditnumber);
    int seconddigit = calcfirst(creditnumber);

if (digits != 13 && digits != 15 && digits != 16)
{
    printf("INVALID\n");
}
else
{
    if (checksum(creditnumber, digits))
    {
        if (firstdigit == 4)
        {
            printf ("VISA\n");
        }
        else if (firstdigit == 5 && (seconddigit > 0 && seconddigit < 6))
        {
            printf("MASTERCARD\n");
        }
        else if (firstdigit == 3 && (seconddigit == 4 || seconddigit == 7))
        {
            printf("AMEX\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("INVALID\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }
}
return 0;
}

long get_number(void)
{
     long creditnumber = get_long("Number: ");
     return creditnumber;
}

int get_digits(long creditnumber)
{
    int digits = 0;
do
{
    creditnumber /= 10;
    digits++;
}
while (creditnumber != 0);

    return digits;
}

int calcfirst(long creditnumber)
{
    int firstdigit;
    int seconddigit;
    int firstnum;

long n = creditnumber;
while (n > 100)
{
    n /= 10;
}
firstnum = n;

firstdigit = firstnum / 10;
seconddigit = firstnum % 10;

return firstdigit;
return seconddigit;
}
```

`

In this code I request a credit card number and then check whether it is valid and then which type of card it is (for the CS50 Harvard course). The check works fine, but when it comes to looking at the first and second digits of the credit card number my code doesn't seem to work. It keeps returning one number as false when it should come back as an AMEX card because the first number is a three and the second number is a seven, and I've checked to ensure that this is true. Does anyone have any idea why this else if condition is not returning the way it should?

Comment: It's not possible to return two values (not like that anyway) from a function. Perhaps use a structure containing the two values and return it?

Comment: So my best bet would simply be to make a separate function to return the second digit?

Comment: Note that a card number is not an integer: it is a string, and that is how it should be handled. Then you get `if(cardnum[0] == '4')`. It makes no sense at all to convert the input string to an integer, and then extract the digits you were originally given.

Comment: Oh that's an interesting way to view it. I researched the solution to this problem and it does it the way I have in this code by turning the credit number into a long, but I can definitely see the merits to this.

Comment: It's the *essential* way to view it. If your card or phone "number" begins with one or more zeros, you have lost them by converting to an integer. It's a beginner's trap to think that a "number" must be an `int` or `long` (or that a "character" must be a `char`).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return two values from a function and both **firstdigit** and **seconddigit** are same.

**for efficient simply change this**

```c
int firstdigit = calcfirst(creditnumber);
int seconddigit = calcfirst(creditnumber);
```

**to this:**

```c
int firstdigit = calcfirst(creditnumber);
int seconddigit = firstdigit%10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your calcfirst function only returns the first number of the Credit card. The second return is never executed. So both firstdigit and seconddigit are actually the the same.

Comment: Thank you for the response. How do I make it so that the second return is executed?

Comment: You cannot return two valuessa from function in C, I suggest you make a function that returns one specified digit from the creditcard. Like calc_nth_digit(long creditcard, int n)

Comment: I just revised the code to only return one value, and then use that to turn it into two values in the else if section which worked. Thank you for the help!